# Why does material UI react stepper doesn't have tab focus?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The material-UI react stepper control steps do not receive the tab focus. Is there a way to enable tabFocus on the steps?

https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already I see tabFocus is exist on the steps but the styles are not show. I think if you add focusRipple props attribute

```
<StepButton focusRipple onClick={handleStep(index)} completed={isStepComplete(index)} {...buttonProps}>
  {label}
</StepButton>
```

true on the StepButton component you might  be able to see the tab focus
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4m4si

Comment: I am just curious why its not available by default because Stepbutton dervies from Buttonbase which has focus ripple available by default

Comment: Its available in ButtonBase documentation and the default value is also false in ButtonBase, 
https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/
As you said StepButton is deriving from ButtonBase the value is also false by default here

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant that a button has focus ripple by default and doesn’t require us to set it to true explicitly. But for stepbutton the focus ripple is visible only when you set it to true in declaration.